# Oracle SQL - Round down dates to quarter

Tags: sql, oracle, date, rounding, truncate

How can I round down hour data to quarters?

```
Eg. 
| Hour (HH24:MI:SS) | Expected result | Query result |
|--|--|--|
| 10:04:00| 10:00:00|10:00:00|
| 10:12:00| 10:00:00|10:15:00|
| 10:14:59| 10:00:00|10:15:00|
| 10:15:00| 10:15:00|10:15:00|
| 10:15:02| 10:15:00|10:15:00|
| 10:16:00| 10:15:00|10:15:00|
```

I wrote something like this, but it only rounding to nearest quarter :/

```
with dates as ( 
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:04:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:12:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:15:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:15:02', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:16:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
)
select d
      ,TRUNC (d) + (ROUND ((d - TRUNC (d)) * 96) / 96)
from dates;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MOD`ulo function to find the number of minutes and seconds to subtract:

```sql
with dates as ( 
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:04:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:12:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual 
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:15:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:15:02', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
   union all
   select to_date('01/01/2022 10:16:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') d from dual
)
select d,
       d - MOD((d - TRUNC(d))*24*60, 15)/24/60 AS rounded
from dates;
```

Which outputs:

> | D | ROUNDED |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-01 10:04:00 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 |
> | 2022-01-01 10:12:00 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 |
> | 2022-01-01 10:14:59 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 |
> | 2022-01-01 10:15:00 | 2022-01-01 10:15:00 |
> | 2022-01-01 10:15:02 | 2022-01-01 10:15:00 |
> | 2022-01-01 10:16:00 | 2022-01-01 10:15:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fbc3c16cd97c580cdfd40536d6ffc70c)*